# Jackson library version confilct

Tags: json, scala, jackson

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11', version: '5.1.2'
```

It's a part of my gradle configuration. and It works find.
When I added 'play-json' library like below to process json string.

```
compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-json_2.11', version: '2.5.13'
```

Errors comes out where scala try to read csv file.

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.8   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)

```
    spark.read
        .option("header", fileHeader)
        .option("charset", charset)
        .csv( "./data/" + filePath) // error here
```

I'm working with scala 2.11 and spark 2.1.0.
Any Idea of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play 2.4.10 works well with Spark 2.1 because the jackson they use are similar

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11', version: '5.1.2'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-json_2.11', version: '2.4.10'
```

Comment: thans you saved me :)

Comment: One more relative question. how did you know play 2.4.10 fit with spark 2.1?

Comment: you can check subdependencies in maven central https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11/2.4.10 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0

Comment: in this case those 2 versions of jackson are not conflictive

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Spark has a dependency on an older version of Jackson and the [Jackson Scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala). I imagine the module isn't playing nice with the more recent version of Jackson that comes along as a dependency of `play-json`.

Try excluding Jackson as a transitive dependency from Spark like this:

```
compile('org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind' 
     exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', module: 'jackson-module-scala_2.11' 
}
```

You could also try adding a direct dependency on Jackson 2.7.8 as well.

Comment: Tried both the ways, 
1. by excluding both jackson-databind and jackson-module-scala 
2. adding direct dependency of jackson 2.7.2 . 

In both the cases, when i try to run the spark job, it fails with the error
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest spark version `3.0.0-preview2`, the below configuration is a working `build.sbt`:

```
name := "coursera"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
val sparkVersion = "3.0.0-preview2"
val playVersion="2.8.1"

val jacksonVersion="2.10.1"

//override if you wish to
//dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % jacksonVersion
//dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % jacksonVersion

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % playVersion
)
```